Print playwright browser in pytest terminal header
I have pytest set up with playwright and can run it with a docker compose command:
docker compose run test pytest /tests --browser-channel chrome

Which outputs:
============================ test session starts =============================
platform linux -- Python 3.12.6, pytest-8.3.3, pluggy-1.5.0
rootdir: /tests
plugins: base-url-2.1.0, playwright-0.5.2
collected 1 item                                                             

tests/test_example.py .                                                   [100%]

============================= 1 passed in 0.02s ==============================

I want to include the browser names in each session. I've tried using the browser_name fixture in the pytest_report_header hook, but fixtures don't work in the report hooks and it errors out.

I was able to add this by checking the config.option Namespace and returning the browser value if found.
Added to my conftest.py file:
def pytest_report_header(config):
    if config.get_verbosity() == 0:
        browser = None
        if config.option.browser_channel is not None:
            browser = config.option.browser_channel
        elif len(config.option.browser) > 0:
            browser = ", ".join(config.option.browser)

        if browser is not None:
            return f"browser: {browser}"

============================ test session starts =============================
platform linux -- Python 3.12.6, pytest-8.3.3, pluggy-1.5.0
browser: chrome
rootdir: /tests
plugins: base-url-2.1.0, playwright-0.5.2
collected 1 item                                                             

tests/test_example.py .                                                [100%]

============================= 1 passed in 0.02s ==============================
============================ test session starts =============================
platform linux -- Python 3.12.6, pytest-8.3.3, pluggy-1.5.0
browser: firefox
rootdir: /tests
plugins: base-url-2.1.0, playwright-0.5.2
collected 1 item                                                             

tests/test_example.py .                                                [100%]

============================= 1 passed in 0.02s ==============================

This is still a little buggy:

--browser-channel chrome is printed as "chrome" and not "chromium"
When passing multiple --browser-channel flags it will only print the last value, but still runs the tests as expected

